# Where are the page setting for the composer in QGIS 3?

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3

When I open the composer I can't see any obvious means of changing the page setup (size or orientation).  QGIS 2 had a tab for this.

Comment: Ack :)  I searched on page size so it never came up.  Is there a way to add something to the so it gets better coverage in searches?  Should I delete my question?

Answer (score 3):

You need to right click anywhere in the composer window this pops up the option to bring up the page properties dialogue

[image]